# Removing code dependency on Greenlets

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I have some code which depends on Greenlets, and need to remove this dependency. 
Can anyone explain to me exactly what I'll need to do?

They would preferably be replaced with threads or (better yet) processes from the multiprocessing module, but anything that relies solely on the Python standard library would be sufficient for my needs.

Functionality can be sacrificed, as I don't need asynchronous code, nor does the code that I am converting (for my uses, not the original implementation).

**UPDATE:**
Specifically, I need to know of alternatives to Greenlet.spawn()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on the structure of your code and high level architecture of your system. If you think that whatever you are using greenlets for can be done using multiprocessing module in the Python Standard library, then you can do that. I think, if you post specific instances than you can get the specific ways to those using multiprocessing. But beware these are two different ways to solve a generic problem of concurrency.